# how to make rpm -ivh *.rpm ignore a specific rpm

Tags: linux, wildcard, rpm

I have to do **rpm -ivh *.rpm** under a directory with lots of rpms. I want to ignore one or two specific rpms. How can I do that?

Comment: Move them away if you can. While this does not solve your question in general, it is the fastest solution for a temporary hack.

Comment: Sorry, I don't own that directory.

Comment: why did I get a downvote for this question? huh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they don't have spaces or newlines in the filenames (which is what I'd expect, for rpms), then the easiest route would be

```
rpm -ivh $(ls *.rpm | grep -v firstbadone | grep -v secondbadone | ...)
```

This will go wrong with spaces, though, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum`.

```
yum install --exclude='*glob*' *.rpm
```

From `yum --help`:

```
-x [package], --exclude=[package]
                      exclude package(s) by name or glob
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find to get the listing of files you want, then call rpm with the appropriate listing.

```
rpm -ivh `find . -type f \( -iname "*.rpm" ! -iname "exclude.rpm" \)`
```